# How to fireup function when multiple dropdown is selected

Tags: jquery

I have three inputs 2 dropdown 1 textinput, whenever user changes any of the inputs I want to fire an ajax fetch function.

I was working on ajax fetch but don't know where the issue is.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#inputState").change() || $("#inputDistrict").change() || $("#inputPincode").keyup(function filter_data()
    {
        $('.filter_data').html('<div id="loading" style="" ></div>');
        var action = 'fetch_data';
        var state = $('#inputState').val();
        var district = $('#inputDistrict').val();
        var pincode = $('#inputPincode').val();
        $.ajax({
            url:"fetch_data.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{action:action, state:state, district:district, pincode:pincode},
            success:function(data){
                $('.filter_data').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the handler inside the `.change(handler)` call, to update your code:

```
$("#inputState").change(fetch);
$("#inputDistrict").change(fetch);
$("#inputPincode").keyup(fetch);

function fetch()
{
    $('.filter_data').html('<div id="loading" style="" ></div>');
    var action = 'fetch_data';
    var state = $('#inputState').val();
    var district = $('#inputDistrict').val();
    var pincode = $('#inputPincode').val();
    $.ajax({
        url:"fetch_data.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{action:action, state:state, district:district, pincode:pincode},
        success:function(data){
            $('.filter_data').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```